# Mark the build as unstable when a junit fails

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline

I deploy a maven project that has JUnit tests. When a test fail, the build is marked as `FAILED`. However, I want it to be marked as `UNSTABLE` when a test fails, and `FAILED` when there is a serious error .
Here is my `Jenkinsfile`:

```groovy
node{
  stage ('Checkout')
  {
    checkout scm
  }
  stage ('Build')
  {
    try {
        sh '''
           mvn clean -B org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install
        '''
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
      } catch (Exception AssertionError) {
        currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
      } finally {
        step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])

    }
  }
}
```

But this is not working for me. I can't catch the `AssertionError` and the build is always marked as `FAILED`. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Could you give a short explanation why you want it that way? Usually, one failed test fails the build and I would be interested in your "special case".

Comment: The need is to distinguish a broken build from builds with failed tests.

Comment: `JUnitResultArchiver` might also modify the build result under the hood if any tests fail. You would have to look at the implementation.

Comment: @mkobit how can I do that please?

Comment: I edited my comment to reflect what I was saying, but just comment out the `JUnitResultArchiver` and see if it remains `UNSTABLE`.

Comment: What are you expecting to be throwing the `AssertionError`? The `mvn` command? If so, I don't think it will be caught the way you expect. I'm pretty sure that, since the `mvn` command is wrapped in an `sh` execution, you're only going to get a success/failure. Maybe try something like `catch(err) { println err }` to see generically if any error is actually being caught.

Comment: You know that builds with failed tests are broken builds, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the xunit plugin instead of the junit plugin which you can configure to set the build to unstable in case a specific number of tests failed.